# Is there a preprocessor for json files?

Tags: json, preprocessor, configuration-files

I have some configuration files that I store the complex object values as serialized json. Currently there is a configuration file for each environment (localhost, dev, prod etc.) and for each installation by client. Most of the values are identically for the configurations between environments but not all. So for three environments and four clients I currently have 12 total files to manage.

If this were a web.config file there would be web.config transforms that would solve the problem. If this was c# I'd have compiler preprocessor directives that could be useed to substitute the different values based on the current build configuration.

Does anyone know of anything that works basically this way or have some good suggestion on tried and true ways to proceed? What I would like is to reduce the number of files down to a single instance for each installation that can suffice for each environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration of configuration always seems a bit overdone to me, but you could use a properties file for the parts that change, and apache ant's `<replace>` task to do the substitutions. Something like this:

```
<replace 
    file="configure.json"
    propertyFile="config-of-config.properties">
  <replacefilter 
    token="@token1@" 
    property="property.key"/>
</replace>
```

Comment: Thanks Gus!  I'm not sure what you mean by "configuration of configuration". It is more similar to a web.config transform with specific value that environmental like as are connection strings. I'm sort of toying with building my own preprocessor for this and just do it in code prior to deserializing.

Comment: Glad to help :) was it useful? (hint, hint :) ).

Comment: I just mean that (assuming you wrote the system being configured) configuration that never changes maybe didn't need to be configuration, and if everything changes you won't gain much.

Comment: Oh, in this case the variant is the client installations. These can be very different from each other. It is just the environmentally aspects of each configuration file that need to change with each environmental build configuration.

Answer (score 2):

[Jsonnet](http://jsonnet.org/) from Google is a language that with with a super-set syntax based on JSON, adding high level language features that help to model data in JSON fromat. The compilation step produces JSON. I have used it in a project to describe complex deployment environments that inherit from one another at times and that share domain attributes albeit utilizing them differently from one instance to another.
As an example, an instance contains applications, tenant subscriptions for those applications, contracts, destinations and so forth. The values for all of these attributes are objects the recur throughout environments.

Their docs are very thorough and don't miss the [std functions](http://jsonnet.org/docs/stdlib.html) because they make for some very powerful data rendering capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [Squirrelistic JSON Preprocessor](https://github.com/Squirrelistic/sjpp) which uses [Golang Text Templates syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) to generate JSON files based on parameters provided.

JSON template can include reference to other templates, use conditional logic, comments, variables and everything else which Golang Text templates package provides.

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to your full stack.

If you're talking about some application that runs solely client-side, with no server-side processing, whatsoever, then there's really no such thing as pre-processing.
You can process the data further before actually using it, but that won't mean that it will be processed prior to the page being served -- it means that people have to sit around, waiting for that to happen before the apps which need that data can be initialized.

The benefit of using JSON, to begin with is that it's just a data-store, and is quite language-agnostic, and quite widely supported, now.  So if it's not 100% client-side, there's nothing stopping you from pre-processing in whatever language you're using on the server, and caching those versions of those files, to serve (and cache) to users, based on their need.

If you really, really need a system to do live processing of config-files, on the client-side, and you've gone through the work of creating app-views which load early, but show the user that they're deferring initialization (ie: "loading..."/spinners), then download a second JSON file, which holds all of the needed implementation-specific data (you'll have 12 of these tiny little files, which should be simple to manage), parse both JSON files into JS objects, and extend the large config object with the additional data in the secondary file.

**Please note:** Use localhost or some other storage facility to cache this, so that for html5-browsers, this longer load only happens one time.

Comment: Thanks Norguard! Your answer is very good but this is entirely on the server it could be 1 for 1 substitution for a web.config but I'm running one site/application for all clients. I originally was store the configuration in a document store (RavenDb) but this was becoming a headache with coordinating the changes between environments for each of the different clients installations. Each time the code gets pushed out the configuration structural changes needed to move with the executing code. My current theory is that I should just move the configuration files with each push of code.

Comment: If it's running server-side, then there's nothing really stopping you from writing a version-number into the cached value.  It might make for an extra call (`isVersionLatest(versionNum)`), but that would be a very light call, and would save the hassle of pushing the whole thing over the wire, every time.  In PHP or PERL or c# or whatever you're serving from, there's nothing stopping you from getting a GET request for a particular type of config, and then getting the big JSON file, getting the tiny "XOR" file for that particular setup, building it out, caching that file (with version) and...

Comment: serving it as a text file to the end user.  With the value cached on the server side, you can do your updates quickly and easily in the tiny specialized files, extend the larger files with the tiny one, create your version of that file-type and cache it. It sounds like the biggest challenge right now is that you haven't frozen the structure of your config.  That's really not something that makes life any easier.  In fact, it means that no matter what you do, you're going to end up redoing a lot of work, until that structure is 100% predictable, all the time, until a major overhaul (v2.0 style)

Answer (score 0):

There is one, https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-variables

Conceptually, it is a function which takes *a string*, JSON contents, sprinkled with specially marked variables and it produces *a string* with those variables resolved. Same like **Sass** or **Less** does for CSS - it's used to DRY up the source code.

Here's an example.

You'd put something like this in JSON file:

```
{
  "firstName": "customer.firstName",
  "message": "Hi %%_firstName_%%",
  "preheader": "%%_firstName_%%, look what's inside"
}
```

Notice how it's DRY — single source of truth for the `firstName` value.

`json-variables` would process it into:

```
{
  "firstName": "customer.firstName",
  "message": "Hi customer.firstName",
  "preheader": "customer.firstName, look what's inside"
}
```

that is, `Hi %%_firstName_%%` would look for `firstName` at the root level (but equally, it could be a deeper path, for example, `data1.data2.firstName`). Resolving also "bubbles up" to the root level, also you can use custom data structures and more.

Missing pieces of a JSON-processing task puzzle are:

- Means to merge multiple JSON files, various ways ([object-merge-advanced](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-merge-advanced))
- Means to orchestrate actions — [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) is good if you're preferred programming language is JS
- Means to get/set values by path ([object-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path) - its notation uses dots only, no brackets `key1.key2.array.2` instead of `key1.key2.array[2]`)
- Means to maintain the same set of keys across set of JSON files - you add a key in one, it's added on all others ([object-fill-missing-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fill-missing-keys))

In described case, we can do at least two approaches: one-to-many, or many-to-many.

Former - Gulp could be "baking" many JSON files from one or more JSON-like source files, `json-variables` DRY-ing up the references.

Later - alternatively, it could be "managed" set of JSON files rendered into set of distribution files — Gulp watches `src` folder, runs [object-fill-missing-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fill-missing-keys) to normalise schemas, maybe even sorting objects (yes, it's possible, [sorted-object](https://github.com/domenic/sorted-object)).

It all depends how similar is the desired set of JSON files and how values are customised and is it done manually or programmatically.